# Google Code Scanner (QR Scanner) shows black screen when launching it

Tags: android, kotlin, google-mlkit

I am trying to use [Google's new code scanner](https://developers.google.com/ml-kit/vision/barcode-scanning/code-scanner) for scanning QR codes in an Android app, when a button is clicked, but I get a black screen.

Here is my code:

```
binding.scanQR.setOnClickListener {
    val options = GmsBarcodeScannerOptions.Builder()
        .setBarcodeFormats(Barcode.FORMAT_QR_CODE, Barcode.FORMAT_AZTEC)
        .build()

    GmsBarcodeScanning.getClient(this, options).startScan().addOnSuccessListener {
        model.onScanAddress(it.rawValue)?.let { address ->
            binding.address.setText(address)
        }
    }.addOnFailureListener {
        Timber.e(it)
    }
}
```

And here is what happens when I click the button:
[image]

---

**There are no error/warn logs, so I'm a bit stuck here. Any ideas?**

Comment: Tried to manage camera permission before launching it ?

Comment: Hey, thanks for replying! I am having the exact same issue as @tzegian.

But the first line in the documentation is "The Google code scanner API provides a complete solution for scanning codes without requiring your app to request camera permission": https://developers.google.com/ml-kit/vision/barcode-scanning/code-scanner

Comment: Yes, exactly what @netcyrax posted, there aren't any camera permission's required nor there are such on the app's settings (in Android Setings).

Comment: That library appears to be using the dynamically downloaded MLKit models. Those downloads can sometimes fail, and I don't know how the library handles such failures. Have you tried updating the Google Play Servcies app?

Comment: @Michael Yes, I am already running on the latest version of Google Play Services.

Comment: I had this issue on my Samsung device, but it worked fine when I tried it on a Google Pixel. Not working on Samsung (or non-Google devices) is .... a severe issue for this library.

Comment: @netcyrax Hmm, interesting, I have this issue also on a Samsung S21 FE 5G.

Comment: Duplicate SO issue here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76358056/getting-a-black-screen-instead-of-a-qr-scanner-while-using-ml-kit-to-scan-barcod

And there's an open bug in Google's tracking system (+1 if you are affected): https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/285007312